# Regex to remove consecutive same numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I am trying to remove all the consecutive numbers using exactly RegEx with JS. I tried two ways the second one passed but I am wondering what is wrong with the first one

First try:

```js
let a = "1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9";
a = a.split(" ").join("");
for (let i of a) {
  a = a.replace(/ii/g, i);
}

console.log(a)
```

Second one

```js
let a = "1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9";
a = a.split(" ").join("");
for (let i of a) {
  a = a.replace(new RegExp(`(${i})(${i})`, "g"), "$1");
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: your first piece of code is literally looking for `'ii'` in the string as opposed to the variable in your for loop.

Comment: btw if you want to learn to understand and write regex by yourself, I'd suggest trying an educational tool like [regexr](https://regexr.com) and playing around in it.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, your first snippet is using a regular expression literal which cannot accept variables from the script. So...

```
/ii/g
```

...would match any occurrence of `'ii'` in a targeted string.

The only way to achieve this functionality is with the `RegExp()` constructor which you demonstrate in the second snippet.

If the motivation behind your question is cleaner code then the following is an alternative approach:

Lookbehind assertions and capture groups in regex make situations like this really simple to achieve. No need to mess around with arrays and loops:

```
const removeSequentialNumbers = (string) =>
  string.replaceAll(/(?<=(?<number>\d))(\s\k<number>)/g, '');
```

[Here is the Regex101 link for your testing](https://regex101.com/r/XWHAjf/1).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good use of lookarounds, but I found that it wasn't as fast (at least in this case) as using back-references. You can see my answer for the code I used to benchmark it.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easier with [match groups and back-references](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html). Just make one match group that matches any number, then repeat that group at least once. To make this work, you'll also need to add a trailing space so the last number can be matched, but then later remove that space. Like this:

```js
let a = "1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9";
let b = (a + ' ').replace(/([1-9]\s)\1+/g, '$1').slice(0, -1);

console.log(b)
```

This method will also preserve the spaces. If you need to remove the spaces, then you can simply strip them from the result like this:

```js
let a = "1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9";
let b = (a + ' ').replace(/([1-9]\s)\1+/g, '$1').replaceAll(' ', '');

console.log(b)
```

I timed this approach against [damonholden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74592594/13376511) and found that it is generally faster (run multiple times, stack snippets is a little finicky):

```js
let a = "1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9";

console.time()
console.log(a.replaceAll(/(?<=(?<number>\d))(\s\k<number>)/g, ''));
console.timeEnd()

console.time()
console.log((a + ' ').replace(/([1-9]\s)\1+/g, '$1').slice(0, -1));
console.timeEnd();
```

Comment: Works without adding a space and slicing it off.

Comment: @caTS It works in this specific example, but it doesn't if another consecutive number is added at the end. For example, it would break on `"1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9 9"` without adding and removing the space.

Comment: running both mine and your solutions in isolation gives similar times, I would check those benchmarks again testing both individually.

Comment: Very interesting. The use of modifiers with groups can avoid using named groups. Maybe it can be a little harder to follow but if speed is important this can be a better alternative 

Answer (score 2):

I think the semantically correct way to do this is with named groups. It lets you match a pattern then refer back to the pattern later in your match so it allows you to identify duplicates easily.

```
a.replaceAll(/(?<number>\d)\s\k<number>/g, "$1")
```

Explanation: It matches a digit \d and it groups it with () and it gives it a name (in this case "number") then I can refer to this match with \k so I can see where the same match appears again.

Then replace with $1 replaces the whole content (in this case two matches separated with a space) with the group.

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences

```js
let a = "1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9"; 
const result = a.replaceAll(/(?<number>\d)\s\k<number>/g, "$1")
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Good solution using backreferences, it is nicer than my answer that adds and removes a space at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = "1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9";

a = a.split(" ").join("");
let b = a.replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1');
let c = b.split("").join(" ")

console.log(c)
```